# Extract DJI drone parameters to XYZ position in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, location, coordinates, game-physics, dji-sdk

I'm currently working on a simulation project using a Mavic Mini and the Mobile SDK to track the current location of the drone in Unity.

So far, I've done the TCP connection between the Unity environment and the Android Application. My next step is to extract the coordinates of the drone and transform them into the Unity coordinates

What I've tried is to use the FlightControllerState to get the XYZ velocity:

`mFlightController = aircraft.getFlightController();`

or
`mState = aircraft.getFlightController().getState();`

However, both of the methods return the 0 and NaN value when I tried to access the velocity value (even I've controlled the drone to move around)

`mState.getVelocityX();`
return 0 if I use `aircraft.getFlightController()` and return NaN if I use

`mState = aircraft.getFlightController().getState();`

Edit*: I did try to use the callback function of the FlightContrllerState

```
mFlightController.setStateCallback(new FlightControllerState.Callback() {
                                @Override
                                public void onUpdate(@NonNull FlightControllerState flightControllerState)
                                {
                                    v1 = Float.toString((float) flightControllerState.getVelocityX());
                                    v2 = Float.toString((float) flightControllerState.getVelocityY());
                                    v3 = Float.toString((float) flightControllerState.getVelocityZ());
                                    strings[0] = v1;
                                    strings[1] = v2;
                                    strings[2] = v3;
                                }
```

Still got the same result (0) :(

Have anybody tried to do this before, please give me some idea on how to solve this problem

Really appreciate your help

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the dji keys?

```
key = FlightControllerKey.create(FlightControllerKey.VELOCITY_X)
DJISDKManager.getInstance().getKeyManager().addListener((DJIKey)key, (@Nullable Object oldValue, @Nullable Object newValue) -> {....}
```

Comment: Let me give it a try